# How to create a more accurate estimate of runtime

Tags: r, time, resources

In my R program I have a main loop which can take a considerable amount of time to complete. Because of this I want to create a warning dialog which provides a more accurate estimate than I have now. Currently in the loop it calls

```
if (loopIteration == 1) {
    sampleTime1 <- sys.time();
}

if (loopIteration == 2) {
    sampleTime2 <- sys.time();
    timeEstimate <- loopLength*difftime(sampleTime2, sampleTime1);
    print(timeEstimate);
}
```

Unfortunately this estimate is inaccurate by about 75%. How can I make this more accurate?

Comment: Presumably both conditions being `loopIteration == 1` is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a function from another unnamed package. The function name in the  base function is `system.time` and the third element it reports is the elapsed time for an expression to execute:

```
> system.time({for(i in 1:1000000) {NULL} })[3]
elapsed 
    0.2
```

Comment: It is from the R base package http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/difftime.html

Comment: I think DWin is talking about the sys.time function you are using.  Not the difftime function.  There is a Sys.time function.  My guess is that your code does not run, but maybe the first s in Sys.time does not need to be capitalized.

Comment: Well, the "S" in `base::Sys.time` certainly _does_ need to be capitalized if we are talking about the base function. So what are we talking about, anyway? Can we have some actual code that runs and some results that demonstrate what is being alleged?